# Can you access the current iterator from a function used by the transform function in c++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

Can you access the current iterator from a function used by the transform function in c++ so that you can reference previous and latter values?
I want to use the transform function to iterate through a vector, performing operations on the vector that rely on values before and after the current value.

For example, say I have a vector with values [1,2,4,3,5,6], and I want to start at the second value, and iterate until the second to last value. On each of those elements, I want to make a new value that equals the sum of the value, and the values next to it in the original.
The ending vector would look like
[7,9,12,14].

```
auto originalsBeginIterator = originalPoints.begin();
auto originalsEndIterator = originalPoints.end();
std::advance(originalsBeginIterator, 1);
std::advance(originalsEndIterator,-1);
std::transform(originalsBeginIterator,originalsEndIterator,alteredValues.begin(),
[](int x) x = { return {previous value} + x + {next value};} 
);
```

Is there any way to reference previous and latter values from the original array when using transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the tool [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) simply doesn't give you a way to do that: it either takes a *unary* predicate to be applied to individual elements of of one collection, or a *binary* predicate to be applied to *corresponding elements* of two collections.

**But the point is that, from the functional programming perspective, what you are trying to do is simply not a transform.**

How can you go about it instead? You could zip that vector, let's call it `v`, the same vector deprived of its first element, and the same vector deprived from its second element; you would then sum the 3 elements of each pair.

Range-v3 gives you a way to do this quite tersely:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/drop.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/zip_with.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace ranges::views;
int main()
{
    // input
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6};

    // to sum 3 ints
    auto constexpr plus = [](int x, int y, int z){ return x + y + z; };

    // one-liner
    auto w = zip_with(plus, v, v | drop(1), v | drop(2));

    // output
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
}
```

`v | drop(1)` gives you a view on the elements `{2,3,4,5,6}`, and `v | drop(2)` on `{3,4,5,6}`; `zip_with` taks a *n*-ary function and *n* ranges and combines the *n*-tuple of corresponding elements from the *n* ranges using the *n*-ary function. So in our case it'll go like this:

```
v                         = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
                             +  +  +  +
v1 = v | drop(1)          = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
                             +  +  +  +
v2 = v | drop(2)          = {3, 4, 5, 6}
zip_with(plus, v, v1, v2) = {6, 9,12,15}
```